# how to populate states and cities of a particular country in html forms ? (dependent picklists)

Tags: html, jquery, state, country, picklist

For a company, there are two addresses. one is registered address and other is wherehouse address. for both registeed & warehouse address i want to add the dependent picklists.(when a country is selected, the states of that selected country only should get populated in states dropdown. and similarly when we select the state the cities of that particular state should get populated.

i found one working example. but the problem here is, when i select the country in registered address, the warehouse address dropdowns are also getting populated (states and cities of warehouse address are also getting effected or changed, i dont want this behaviour)and vice versa. how to fix this issue

below is my example.

```html
-
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <p>Rgistered Address</p><br><br>
    <select name="country" class="countries order-alpha" id="countryId">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>
    <select name="state" class="states order-alpha" id="stateId">
      <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" class="cities order-alpha" id="cityId">
      <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <p>warehouse Address</p><br><br>
    <select name="country" class="countries order-alpha" id="countryId">
      <option value="">Select Country</option>
    </select>
    <select name="state" class="states order-alpha" id="stateId">
      <option value="">Select State</option>
    </select>
    <select name="city" class="cities order-alpha" id="cityId">
      <option value="">Select City</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
```

Comment: Just write it yourself its not that hard, nobody can edit : `geodata.solutions/includes/countrystatecity.js` You haven posted any relevant code of it also. Doubt anyone will go dig it and then write JS to possibly overwrite it. And no one here will go populate your drop-downs manually itslef and start whole new JS for you. Try it yourself and if you get stuck ask for help.

Comment: Also you have multiple same id's, those CAN NOT be the same, id's are unique.

Comment: @ikiK ,added the js code that  i was using in the app. Please check

Comment: Sorry to much code to go threw. 200 lines when tided... You should see what [mre] is and why is important.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to separate address types by changing inputs id to

```
<select name="country" class="countries order-alpha" id="countryIdRegistered">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>

<select name="country" class="countries order-alpha" id="countryIdWhereHouse">
  <option value="">Select Country</option>
</select>
```

So, you can manage them like you want.